# lxml on windows for python2.7 doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, lxml

I have installed lxml with *.exe*.
[image: installed]

However, when I use it, it doesn't work.
[image: error]

So, how can I deal with this problem?

---

BTW, when I didn't use *.exe* for installation, I couldn't install the package with *!pip install lxml* because **libxml2 and libxslt** couldn't be found. Are there any connections between them?

Answer (score 0):

> For MS Windows, recent lxml releases feature community donated binary
>   distributions, although you might still want to take a look at the
>   related FAQ entry. If you fail to build lxml on your MS Windows system
>   from the signed and tested sources that we release, consider using the
>   binary builds from PyPI or the unofficial Windows binaries that
>   Christoph Gohlke generously provides.

If you do not want to deal with binary builds, I recommend you use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads),just download and install it.

Anaconda is the leading open data science platform powered by Python. The open source version of Anaconda is a high performance distribution of Python and R and includes over 100 of the most popular Python, R and Scala packages for data science.

Additionally, you'll have access to over **720 packages(contains lxml)** that can easily be installed with conda, our renowned package, dependency and environment manager, that is included in Anaconda.